# Loading shrads of llama 2 when inferencing it by huggingface takes too long

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, llama

It happens when I trying to inference llama2. The following is my code:

```
from huggingface_hub import login
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import transformers
import torch

access_token = 'my_access_token'

login(token = access_token)

# Hugging face repo name
model = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf" #chat-hf (hugging face wrapper version)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    task = "text-generation",
    model=model,
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    low_cpu_mem_usage=True,
    max_shard_size="200MB",
    device_map="auto"
)

sequences = pipeline(
    'I liked "Breaking Bad" and "Band of Brothers". Do you have any recommendations of other shows I might like?\n',
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=10,
    top_p = 0.9,
    temperature = 0.2,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    max_length=200, # can increase the length of sequence
)

for seq in sequences:
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
```

And there is my environment:

```
Package            Version
------------------ ----------
accelerate         0.26.1
bitsandbytes       0.42.0
Brotli             1.0.9
certifi            2023.11.17
cffi               1.16.0
charset-normalizer 2.0.4
cryptography       41.0.7
filelock           3.13.1
fsspec             2023.12.2
gmpy2              2.1.2
huggingface-hub    0.20.2
idna               3.4
Jinja2             3.1.2
MarkupSafe         2.1.3
mkl-fft            1.3.8
mkl-random         1.2.4
mkl-service        2.4.0
mpmath             1.3.0
networkx           3.1
numpy              1.26.3
opencv-python      4.9.0.80
packaging          23.2
Pillow             10.0.1
pip                23.3.1
psutil             5.9.7
pycparser          2.21
pyOpenSSL          23.2.0
PySocks            1.7.1
PyYAML             6.0.1
regex              2023.12.25
requests           2.31.0
safetensors        0.4.1
scipy              1.11.4
setuptools         68.2.2
sympy              1.12
tokenizers         0.15.0
torch              2.1.2
torchaudio         2.1.2
torchvision        0.16.2
tqdm               4.66.1
transformers       4.36.2
triton             2.1.0
typing_extensions  4.9.0
urllib3            1.26.18
wheel              0.41.2
```

GPU:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.86.10              Driver Version: 535.86.10    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090        On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 44%   52C    P8              23W / 350W |     18MiB / 24576MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080        On  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8              22W / 320W |    299MiB / 10240MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
Python version:3.11.7
There is no other problems but the low speed. It takes a hour to load the check point shards into gpu.

I don't why this happens and how to fix it. Just provide some thoughts and discuss about it!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.